# Centrar formulario de busqueda en el navbar con Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Bootstrap 5 y a la hora de colocar un navbar tengo problemas para centrar el formulario de búsqueda.
Actualmente está situado a la izquierda después del menú y quiero colocarlo justo en el centro del navbar.

Así se ve ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo el código:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
                expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                       data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-2 ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Iniciar sesión / Registrarse</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Para enriquecer un poco la pregunta: ¿dónde deben aparecer el campo y botón de búsqueda cuando se muestra el botón de menú hamburguesa? ¿Dentro del propio menú colapsado o al lado de navbar-link?

Comment: @padaleiana en principio pensaba ponerlo dentro del menú colapsado quedando primero los ul y por ultimo el campo y botón de búsqueda aunque bien es cierto que está opción nunca llego a convencerme prefiriendo dejarlo fuera del menú colapsado en el centro entre el navbar-brand y el navbar-toggler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con el css `position:absolute`, `left:50%` y `right:0%` en los elementos de busqueda y login respectivamente. Usando el framework de Bootstrap puedes aprovechar sus clases `position-absolute`, `start-50` y `end-0` que son los equivalentes al css mencionado antes.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5 css -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    @media(max-width: 991px){
        .navbar-search, .navbar-login {
            position:static !important;
        }
    }
</style>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
                  expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                          data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                          Dropdown
                      </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li>
                              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                          </li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="navbar-search d-flex position-absolute start-50">
                  <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
              <ul class="navbar-login navbar-nav mr-2 position-absolute end-0">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Iniciar sesión / Registrarse</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Bootstrap 5 js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: con `position-absolute` el formulario y el login se descolocan cuando el menú colapsa. Pulsas el botón hamburguesa para mostrar el menú y es ahí donde estos dos elementos están descolocados

Comment: Lo actualicé añadiendo una `@media` en css. Presta atención, que añadí una clase nueva a los dos elementos interesados para poder acceder a ellos en el css.